# Paypal not prepopulating address details

Tags: html, paypal, populate

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.blaa.co.uk/ipn_subscribe.asp">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="blaaa@blaa.co.uk">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.blaablaa.co.uk/thankyou.asp?oid=955">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Purchase">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="955">                 
                                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="85">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">                                          
                                    <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="5 Birkin Close">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="knutsford">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="GB">
                                    <INPUT id="email" type="hidden" name="email" value="test@test.com">                 

                                    <INPUT type="image" name="Continue" src="NewImages/continue1.jpg" alt="Continue to payment merchant to pay for your purchase">                                      
                                </FORM>
```

Any idea why this does pre populate the Adddress details if you do a credit card purchase?It looks fine to me.

The form is calling paypay - https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. The image is the button that sends the form to paypal. It is going to paypal and not prepopulating the address details in paypal if you want to pay by creditt card. Any ideas why please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this in your code it will work and also enable auto return ul option in your account in website payment prefrence under the selling prefrence under profile under my account option

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://abctest.com./purchase/thank-you.php">
```

(edit show code...)

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.blaablaa.co.uk/thankyou.asp?oid=955"> is already in there

Comment: Sorry realed that there is acutually an http:// infront of the blaablaa in my real code. I have accidentally deleted it when I was pasting the code and removing the name of the actual site.